# ggplot - Bar Plot Aesthetics Error

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am just getting started with R and I am trying to plot some dummy data that I made which I have loaded as a dataframe, however, after a lot of trial and error and searching I tried to make a barplot of some of the columns and the following code did not work:

```
Termcount <- count(dummydata$Term)
ggplot(data=dummydata, aes(x=Term, y=Termcount, fill=Term)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

However,  the following code did and generated the plot I was after but I can't understand why.

```
ggplot() + aes(dummydata$Term, fill=dummydata$Term) + geom_bar()
```

This generates the following plot:

[image]

When the first code is run I am presented with the following error:

*Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (17): x, y, fill*

If required I can upload the data if that will help.

Comment: in the first one there s no `Termcount` column in the dummydata

Comment: Please post (a part of) your data.frame here so we see what it looks like and help you better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments above have said, `ggplot()` wants all of the `aes()` arguments to be column names in you data, `dummydata`, and that is why it's giving you the error. If you added your "count" variable as a new column it would work, something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

data(iris)

dummy <- iris %>% count(Species)

ggplot(data = dummy, aes(Species, y = n, fill = Species)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

The above code is essentially what `geom_bar()` is doing "under the hood" in your second example because it defaults to using using `stat = "count"`. FYI `geom_col()` is the `stat = "identity"` versions of `geom_bar()`.

BTW welcome to SO, it always a good idea to include a tiny data example ( either via table format or `dput()` ) or use one of the built in data sets like `data(iris)`. Example data plus example code and your expected output will allow people to help better and ensure that you are getting your specific problem solved.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome. So if I did not want to add a count column to the dataframe I would be best using the example that worked in my original code? Or is it recommended to add a count column? 
When posting data, is uploading CSV files acceptable or is dput() sufficient?

Comment: I think your second example would be the "best" option. No need to create new columns if you don't need them. `dput()` is the gold standard for reproducible data because it captures everything about your data structure, so all the classes and factor levels will be identical. I would try to avoid csvs when possible because it requires a secondary site (like DropBox or GoogleDrive) and requires others to download files (potential security concerns and just extra work)

Comment: Thanks for the tips Nate.